# Is it true that once we log into VPN, it is as if we are at the remote location?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

Say, if we are in San Francisco, and then once we log into the VPN of the San Jose company, then it will be as if we are in San Jose? (all our network requests will start to go out from San Jose?)

So if we are in San Francisco, and we log into a VPN to Boston, and then look at a webpage whose web server is in Oregon, then the request will go from San Francisco to Boston by VPN, and then from Boston, send a request back to Oregon?

And then the Oregon server will send data to Boston, and then by VPN, send it back to San Francisco?

Comment: In order to answer this question, we would need to better understand how the VPN is configured, which is not currently possible with the information you provided.  The simplest method of determining this information, is to use a geolocation website of your choice, and determining what that website believes is your location.  Please edit your question with that information while connected to the VPN in question.

Comment: Google Maps is a horrible geolocation tool.  I was thinking more of a website that displays your IP address (and location)

Answer (score 3):

This depends whether your VPN has been configured to use a [split tunnel.](https://karneliuk.com/2016/02/split-tunneling-in-cisco-vpn-client-and-cisco-anyconnect/)

You can see your IP address and GeoIP-determined location using a tool like [this](http://geoiplookup.net/). If your VPN has been configured to route all your traffic through it, this tool will show the geographic location of the VPN endpoint. If your VPN has been configured with a split tunnel, your traffic to the wider internet will not cross the VPN and the GeoIP tool will show your approximate location.